# Configure a field for indexation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to configure a property in order that ES indexes it as I want I'd like that "CDE-250" could be found with "CDE", "cde", "cde-" or "CDE-"
The search should not be case sensitive and the "-" character shoud be indexed/analysed also
I was thinking to do it this way

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, indexAnalyzer = "whitespace", searchAnalyzer="whitespace" )
private String model;
```

Thanks for your help

[**UPDATE**]
I have added this file oss-search.json in src/main/elasticsearch/oss-search.json

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "oss_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 20
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "oss": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "oss_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class I'd like to configure for elasticsearch

```
@Document(indexName = "device")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elasticsearch/oss-search.json")
public class Device implements Serializable {
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, indexAnalyzer = "oss")
    private String model;
}
```

But I'm having the following error

```
2016-11-17 16:31:13.821 ERROR 15892 --- [           main]     .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [oss] not found for field [model]
```

Comment: The `whitespace` analyzer alone won't do it. You should create a custom analyzer leveraging an `edgeNGram` tokenizer and the `lowercase` token filter.

Comment: How should I do it with spring-data please ?

Comment: Hey val, can you please refer?